# Ubuntu Through VirtualBox - Scaling Issues in 4K Screens

Tags: virtualbox, display, display-resolution

I have recently leaped into Ubuntu through VirtualBox on my laptop, and I am loving the experience. However, I have one problem that is bothering me all the time.

From VirtualBox, I am using the guest addition to auto-resize my VM screen when I change the window size. I have got it to work with the 4K panel on my laptop, and the scale of 200% works perfectly; the default 100% is too small to use on a 15 inch display. The problem is that every time I resize the window, the display scale goes back to 100%. I have to manually go to settings and select the 200% scale, which is quite inconvenient.

Thus, I was wondering if there is any way to fix the scale to 200%, even while using the auto-resize function. I have searched the Internet for nearly an hour, but haven't seen any similar cases nor solutions...